# How to Register a Guest User Programatically in magento 2

Tags: magento2, registration, customer-registration, guest

How can I register a Guest Customer on Magento 2 programmatically please don't provide any module or 3rd party extension. Can anyone please help!

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code:

```
<?php

class addCustomer implements \YourVendor\YourModule\Api\AppcustomerManagementInterface
{
    ...
    protected $_customerFactoryMain;

    protected $_customerInterfaceFactory;
    
    protected $_encryptorInterface;

    protected $_customerRepositoryInterface;

    public function __construct(
        ...
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactoryMain,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory $customerInterfaceFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface $encryptorInterface,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
    ) {
        ...
        $this->_customerFactoryMain = $customerFactoryMain;
        $this->_customerInterfaceFactory = $customerInterfaceFactory;
        $this->_encryptorInterface = $encryptorInterface;
        $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
    }
    ...

    $email = 'johndoe@ymail.com';

    /**
     * check whether the email address is already registered or not
     */
    $customerCheck = $this->_customerFactoryMain->create();
    $customerCheck->setWebsiteId(1);
    $checkEmail = $customerCheck->loadByEmail($email)->getId();
    
    /**
     * if email address is already registered, return the error message.
     * else, create new customer account.
     */
    if ($checkEmail) {
        $customerRecord[0]['code'] = 0;
        $customerRecord[0]['message'] = "A customer with the same email address already exists.";
        return $customerRecord;
    } else {
        $createCustomer = $this->_customerInterfaceFactory->create();
        $createCustomer->setStoreId(0); // Default Store ID
        $createCustomer->setWebsiteId(1); // Your Website ID
        $createCustomer->setEmail($email);
        $createCustomer->setFirstname('John');
        $createCustomer->setLastname('Doe');

        // set encrypted password.
        $hashedPassword = $this->_encryptorInterface->getHash('JohnDoe@123', true);
        $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->save($createCustomer, $hashedPassword);

        $customerRecord[0]['code'] = 1;
        $customerRecord[0]['message'] = "User register successfully";
        return $customerRecord;
    }
}
```